# how to define zip function over trees in haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

`data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a ) (Tree a)`

I can't figure out how to write a tree version of `zip` and `zipWith` functions in Haskell.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do the trees have to be congruent?

Comment: Learn you a haskell has a very relevant chapter on this: http://learnyouahaskell.com/zippers

Comment: @Dave I think he is talking about having a two trees `Node (Leaf 1) (Leaf 2)` and `Node (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)` become `Node (Leaf (1,2)) (Leaf (2,3))`.  The zippers in that link are more complex then what he/she is talking about.

Comment: @Davorak It's a fair assumption. Maybe the OP can give us an example of what he/she is talking about. Judging from the kind of question I'm assuming you're right and its something simpler.

Comment: What result would you want from `zip (Leaf 1) (Node (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3))`?

Answer (score 7):

Your tree does not allow well formed empty trees - you can make a dodgy one `Node undefined undefined` but this is not very good. As others have commented a simpleminded treeZip will need both trees to have the same shape to get a "good" result.

```
zipTree :: Tree a -> Tree b -> Tree (a,b)
zipTree (Leaf a)     (Leaf b)     = Leaf (a,b)
ZipTree (Node l1 r1) (Node l2 r2) = 
    let l = zipTree l1 l2
        r = zipTree r1 r2 
    in Node l r 

-- Problems...
zipTree (Node _ _)  (Leaf _)   = Node undefined undefined
ZipTree (Leaf _)    (Node _ _) = Node undefined undefined
```

Note that simpleminded tree zipping truncates on shape not just "length" (if shapes don't match it will truncate) - this is more severe than lists which truncate "on length" (strictly speaking lists do truncate on "shape" but the "shape" must always be the same).

For this reason if I was writing a Tree library I wouldn't define zipTree.